# How can I make parabolic curves in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I make a graph like this with `matplotlib`?

[image]

At first, I thought it would just need to graph X and Y like

```
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Then throw it up with `plt.plot(X, Y)` but clearly X and Y are relative(?) so it doesn't.

I don't particularly care about having colours, like the colouring in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `X` and `Y` lists, you can turn them into the 'curve' figure like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
Y = [10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]

for x,y in zip(X, Y):
    x1 = [0, x]
    y1 = [y, 0]
    plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.show()
```

(and I think the result is a hyperbola. To get a parabola, the axes would need to be at a different angle)

Comment: This seems to be it, I understand how that works. Thanks so much